# Infinite loop with do while function

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

I am trying to run some code within a do while function:

```
do {
    printf("\nThis game has two different modes: I Guess, You Guess\n");
    Sleep(2000);
    printf("Which mode do you want to play?\n");
    cin >> mStr;
    cout << "Are you sure you want to play " << mStr << " mode?";
    cin >> choice;
} while (choice != "No");
```

However, every time I enter the mStr (a char array), it just restarts. It doesn't even perform the cout.

Here are the char arrays called:

```
char mStr[10];
char choice[4];
```

On a side note, how could I use printf() instead of cout for that? I am trying to get practice with out.

Edit:

Here is the new code:

```
do {
    printf("\nThis game has two different modes: I Guess, You Guess\n");
    Sleep(2000);
    printf("Which mode do you want to play?\n");
    cin >> mStr;
    printf("Are you sure you want to play %s mode?", mStr); //Cuts off here and doesnt display the 'Guess' part of I Guess
    cin >> choice;
} while (strcmp(cKey, choice) != 1);
```

Comment: Can you give more information? What is `choice`? What is `mStr`?

Comment: You should stick to one type of input/output. Either use `printf` and `scanf`, or use `std::cin` and `std::cout`.

Comment: How are you declaring choice?

Comment: How are you declaring mStr?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't executing the `cout << ...` line? It might just be buffering the output because you haven't terminated it with `std::endl` or `std::flush`

Comment: @Xymostech As stated in the OP, I said I want to be able to use printf instead of cout, but I don't know how to do it with a variable. I have also edited it to include the definitions of the character arrays.

Comment: `printf("Are you sure you want to play %s mode", mStr );`  If you look at the documentation for printf you should be able to find the ton of different formatting options available.  That said, `std::cout << ...` is less likely to go horribly wrong. :)

Comment: Okay. So I changed the cout to printf and did strcmp(), but it still doesn't work. It ends after the text is printed.

Answer (score 5):

You can't compare char array by using `!=`,  you need to use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp), for sample:

```
while (strcmp(choice, "No")!=0)
```

or simply change:

```
std::string mStr;
std::string choice;
```

then you can call

```
while (choice != "No")
```

**Edit**:

As Jarryd mentioned in my comment, if you enter over chars more than length of mStr,choice it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Also he is reading into a bounded buffer with an unbounded read. This is Bad.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Sorry, I am a new coder. Now it says "Are you sure you want to play I mode?" and then quits.

Comment: @billz, Actually, anything over 3 characters is UB. If you enter "abc", it contains "abc\0".

Comment: thx chris.  @Pon-3, what's your code updated to?

Comment: @billz Updated in the original post.

Comment: @Pon-3 what's cKey? also should !=0 if you want to enter `No` and quit while loop

Comment: @billz I set char cKey[4] as the value Yes. I want Yes to quit the loop. I accidently had ckey and choice backwards.

Comment: @Pon-3 you need to know strcmp return value, check this reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp

Comment: @billz That still doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20975/discussion-between-pon-3-and-billz)

Answer (score 2):

You should never compare strings with the plain equality and inequality operators `==` and `!=`. Instead you should use an appropriate function like [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the problem, though, right? Since it's a do-while loop, the `cout` should execute.